# No row at position (-1) - SQL Server when trying to save DataTable changes

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a Windows Forms data entry applet for entering data into a small SQL Server database. I keep seeing this error when trying to save my new record after clicking `AddNewItem` button on the binding navigator component.

[image: Error Message]

My code on clicking the save button on the binding navigator looks like this:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            this.Validate();

            int currentPosition = this.witsStatusDBDataSet.TestCase.Rows.Count - 1;
            WitsStatusDBDataSet.TestCaseRow row = (WitsStatusDBDataSet.TestCaseRow)witsStatusDBDataSet.TestCase.Rows[currentPosition];
            row.AcceptChanges();

            witsStatusDBDataSet.TestCase.AcceptChanges();
            this.testCaseBindingSource.EndEdit();

            int current = witsStatusDBDataSet.TestCase.Rows.Count - 1;

            testCaseTableAdapter.Update(this.witsStatusDBDataSet.TestCase.Rows[current]);
            WitsStatusDBEntry.WitsStatusDBDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager manager = new TableAdapterManager();
            manager.UpdateAll(witsStatusDBDataSet);

            SysTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2500);
            statusLabel1.Text = "Updated successfully.";
            SysTimer.Start();
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            string msg = exc.Message + " : " + exc.StackTrace;
            Clipboard.SetText(msg);
            MessageBox.Show(msg);
        }
}
```

If I enter the data manually in SQL Server Mgmt Studio, the binding navigator successfully loads it and I can use Move Next and Move Previous successfully.

But if I have a brand-new database that has just been deployed, with no records, I get this error.

I checked StackOverflow for similar issues, but nothing seemed to be the same situation.

Comment: If there's no data, `this.witsStatusDBDataSet.TestCase.Rows.Count` will be 0. Then you subtract 1 from that and it becomes -1 and try to access a row at index -1, which doesn't exist. Your error seems straightforward. What specifically don't you understand about how to resolve this?

Comment: That was it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I re-coded the method, based on mason's comment. Here is the working code:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            WitsStatusDBDataSet.TestCaseRow row = null;
            this.Validate();

            int currentPosition = this.witsStatusDBDataSet.TestCase.Rows.Count - 1;
            if(currentPosition == -1)
            {
                row = AddRowToDataTable(testCase: witsStatusDBDataSet.TestCase);
            }

            if (row == null)
            {
                currentPosition = this.witsStatusDBDataSet.TestCase.Rows.Count - 1;
            }
            row.AcceptChanges();

            witsStatusDBDataSet.TestCase.AcceptChanges();
            this.testCaseBindingSource.EndEdit();

            testCaseTableAdapter.Update(row);
            testCaseTableAdapter.InsertCase(row.Title, row.IsAutomated, row.Description, row.State, row.Area, row.Iteration, row.Priority,
                row.Severity, row.Owner, row.CreatedDate, row.ModifiedDate, row.TFS_Case_ID, row.TFSInstance);


            WitsStatusDBEntry.WitsStatusDBDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager manager = new TableAdapterManager();
            manager.Connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=WitsStatusDB;Integrated Security=True");
            manager.UpdateAll(witsStatusDBDataSet);

            SysTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2500);
            statusLabel1.Text = "Updated successfully.";
            SysTimer.Start();
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            string msg = exc.Message + " : " + exc.StackTrace;
            Clipboard.SetText(msg);
            MessageBox.Show(msg);
        }
    }
```

Notice I had to call "AddRowToDataDable()" - that method simply transfers the contents of the Windows Form to the TestCaseRow object.